# printing multidimensional array on a same key number, in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array called **$users** (below), that i would like to print **first_name** and **last_name** together.

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Tom
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => McDonald
            [1] => Terry
        )

)
```

I used foreach loop but the problem is, the foreach loop print:

```
foreach ($users['first_name'] as $key => $first_name) {
    foreach ($users['last_name'] as $key => $last_name) {
        echo "$first_name ";
        echo "$last_name<br />";

    }

}
```

**Result:**

```
John McDonald --> that's what I want
John Terry --> I don't want this
Tom McDonald --> I don't want this
Tom Terry --> That's what I want
```

I put a break inside my foreach loop and again I don't get the right result I want.

Note: I know how to solve this issue by using **for** loop but since the number of users change inside my database, I wouldn't know how many **for loop counts** I need, unless I count the number of rows in array and make the for loop analysis based on that. But i am not looking to use for loop, does any one know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you use the value of `$key`, you don't need to predetermine the count, and indeed you don't even need an inner loop.

```
foreach ($users['first_name'] as $key => $first_name) {
  // no inner loop needed.
  // Use $key to retrieve the associated last_name
  echo "$first_name {$users['last_name'][$key]}\n";
}

// Output:
// John McDonald
// Tom Terry
```